# Failsafe for billing system?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, billing

I currently have a billing system where a nightly script checks for subscriptions that expire a month from the date the script is run, eg:

```
 Subscription.where(:expires => (Date.today + 30.days)).find_each do |sub|
  unless sub.month_reminder_sent
    reminder.total += 1
    reminder.subscriptions << sub
    BillingMailer.monthly_reminder(sub.user).deliver
    sub.month_reminder_sent = true
  end
```

And I have another set to run at a week before expiration. Subs automatically expire if they are not renewed (I just check that the `sub.expiry_date` has not yet passed to check if a sub is active or not).

What contingencies do I need in place in case the server is down? Or a script does not run or fails? (Therefore missing some records.)

Is the above even the best way to go about billing? Or am I worrying needlessly and the above will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

Add an another, date,  column to your Model (i.e. processed_date) which you need to update during your check, then add an additional condition to your script which will process all expired records + these ones not processed before. In case server is down or script was not execute correctly - you will process missed records next time. Also consider some reports, i.e.: number of records processed, number of records processed from previous runs, etc.